# Change chrome extension icon on create of tab (extension page) and set to default when that particular tab is close?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I tried with  **chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: "play.png"});** but it not chnaged when tab is close also I tried to pass **chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: "play.png", tabID});** in this icon chnage with i sifted to other tab.

I want to set Icon which Change on tab create and it not change to the default icon until that tab not close.

Comment: 1) `tabID` should be `tabId`. 2) It's better if you show the actual [MCVE](/help/mcve)

Comment: I used tabId but here it is a mistake to write.

Comment: Without MCVE it's impossible to help.